# Displaying images from database in a popup on clicking table row in php

Tags: php, html

I have a table with field "Photo",This field consists of many image names in my database.
On clicking any row of my table, I need these images to appear in a popup.

This is my table:

```html
<table id="tab">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Photo</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Roy</td><td>US</td><td>selfie1.jpg,selfie2.jpg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Elina</td><td>LA</td><td>selfie3.jpg,selfie4.jpg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Table row3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I do this ? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are good at javascript use tinybox library.

http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinybox/